# How to run a particular test on my local machine only, using pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have a couple of tests which I'd like to run on my local machine, but not on CI.

I'm using pytest, how do I go about this?

I could test to see that there's a particular environment key, and only run the test if it's present, something like:

```py
def test_something():
    if 'key' in os.environ:
        < do test stuff >
```

I feel as though there's probably a better approach though, perhaps using some pytest method / decorator that I'm unaware of.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python, how to mark some tests to only execute when a condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69032204/in-python-how-to-mark-some-tests-to-only-execute-when-a-condition-is-met)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the feature [skipif](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/skipping.html#id1) of pytest:

> **`skipif`**
>
> If you wish to skip something conditionally then you can use skipif instead.
>
> ```
> import sys
>
>
> @pytest.mark.skipif(sys.version_info < (3, 7), reason="requires python3.7 or higher")
> def test_function():
>     ...
> ```

So try something like:

```
@pytest.mark.skipif("key" not in os.environ)
def test_something():
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, using the env variable seemed reasonable then? I wasn't sure if that was a bit shaky, but not sure how else to do it. Thank you for highlighting how to do so with pytest though

Comment: I think using environment variables is reasonable as it is more flexible instead of checking platform versions (which would fail in case there are changes with the machine used thus might require constant updates).